# Get 3D surface grown by constant distance

Tags: graphics3d, computational-geometry, distance

There is a nice [example](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/basic-and-formula-regions/compute-region-distance.html.en) of how to generate an isometric visualisation of surfaces which are at a constant distance from a given region.

All these examples are just working on one single region. If one tries to apply this functionality to RegionUnions then the evaluation does not yield any results. E.g. a simple union of two cuboids with subsequent plotting of the surface which is 0.25 away from their surfaces yields no result:

```
ContourPlot3D[Evaluate@RegionDistance[RegionUnion[
   Cuboid[{-5, -5, 0}, {5, 5, 1}], 
   Cuboid[{-10, -10, -10}, {10, 10, 0}]], {x, y, z}], 
   {x, -7, 7}, {y, -7, 7}, {z, 0, 2}, 
   Mesh -> None, Contours -> {0.25}, 
   ContourStyle -> ColorData[94, "ColorList"], Lighting -> "Neutral",
   BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

whereas the simpler command with just one cuboid generates the expected result:

```
ContourPlot3D[Evaluate@RegionDistance[
   Cuboid[{-5, -5, 0}, {5, 5, 1}], {x, y, z}], 
   {x, -7, 7}, {y, -7, 7}, {z, 0, 2}, 
   Mesh -> None, Contours -> {0.25}, 
   ContourStyle -> ColorData[94, "ColorList"], Lighting -> "Neutral",
   BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Potentially the functionality is just limited to single entities and not unions? Any ideas how to achieve this for Region Unions or Intersections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try evaluating your [`RegionDistance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDistance) object for a point you will see that it doesn't work:

```
RegionDistance[
    RegionUnion[Cuboid[{-5,-5,0},{5,5,1}],Cuboid[{-10,-10,-10},{10,10,0}]],
    {1,-1,2}
] //InputForm
```

> RegionDistance[Polyhedron[{{-5., -5., 0.}, {5., -5., 0.}, {5., -5., 1.}, {-5., -5., 1.},
> {5., 5., 0.}, {-5., 5., 0.}, {-5., 5., 1.}, {5., 5., 1.}, {5., -5., -10.}, {-5., -5.,
> -10.}, {-5., 5., -10.}, {5., 5., -10.}, {10., -5., -10.}, {10., 5., -10.}, {10., 5.,
> 0.}, {10., -5., 0.}, {-10., 5., -10.}, {-10., -5., -10.}, {-10., -5., 0.}, {-10., 5.,
> 0.}, {10., 10., -10.}, {-10., 10., -10.}, {-10., 10., 0.}, {10., 10., 0.}, {-10.,
> -10., -10.}, {10., -10., -10.}, {10., -10., 0.}, {-10., -10., 0.}},
> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {6, 1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8, 3}, {4, 3, 8, 7}, {9, 10, 11,
> 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16}, {14, 13, 9, 12}, {16, 15, 5, 2}, {17, 18, 19, 20}, {10, 18,
> 17, 11}, {6, 20, 19, 1}, {21, 22, 23, 24}, {22, 17, 20, 23}, {14, 21, 24, 15}, {25,
> 26, 27, 28}, {18, 25, 28, 19}, {26, 13, 16, 27}, {22, 21, 14, 12, 11, 17}, {15, 24,
> 23, 20, 6, 5}, {13, 26, 25, 18, 10, 9}, {28, 27, 16, 2, 1, 19}}], {1, -1, 2}]

This is why you don't get a plot. One possible workaround is to discretize your cuboids. Another optimization is to create the [`RegionDistanceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDistanceFunction) and then to use it. So:

```
rdf = RegionDistance @ RegionUnion[
    DiscretizeRegion @ Cuboid[{-5,-5,0},{5,5,1}],
    DiscretizeRegion @ Cuboid[{-10,-10,-10},{10,10,0}]
];

ContourPlot3D[
    rdf[{x,y,z}],
    {x,-7,7}, {y,-7,7}, {z,0,2},
    Mesh->None,
    Contours->{0.25},
    ContourStyle->ColorData[94,"ColorList"],
    Lighting->"Neutral",
    BoxRatios->Automatic
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`Min` work or not?

```
reg1 = Cuboid[{-5, -5, -12}, {5, 5, 12}];
reg2 = Cuboid[{-10, -10, -10}, {10, 10, 10}];
ContourPlot3D[
 Min[RegionDistance[reg1, {x, y, z}], 
   RegionDistance[reg2, {x, y, z}]] // Evaluate, {x, -15, 
  15}, {y, -15, 15}, {z, -15, 15}, Mesh -> None, Contours -> {0.25}, 
 ContourStyle -> ColorData[94, "ColorList"], Lighting -> "Neutral", 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: `reg1 = Cuboid[{-5, -5, -12}, {5, 5, 12}];
reg2 = Cuboid[{-10, -10, -10}, {10, 10, 10}];
RegionPlot3D[
 Min[RegionDistance[reg1, {x, y, z}], 
    RegionDistance[reg2, {x, y, z}]] <= .25 // Evaluate, {x, -15, 
  15}, {y, -15, 15}, {z, -15, 15}, Mesh -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[94, "ColorList"], Lighting -> "Neutral", 
 PlotPoints -> 100, BoxRatios -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]`